Use "wrong" polarity MOSFET to switch low-voltage signal
Probably this has been asked before, but I don't quite know how to describe it...
Goal: I need to connect/disconnect at 0.2V voltage source from my circuit while being able to deliver ~100mA. Since this is lower than any of the typical gate threshold voltages for MOSFETs, I thought of the following:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
So instead of the typical P-MOSFET with source on the high side, I would be using a N-MOSFET with the source on the low side. Since the high side voltage is so low, the MOSFET should be non-conducting when the gate is low, and conducting when it is high (since the source on the low side cannot go above 0.2V, so V_GS is above the threshold.
Would this work, using e.g. a DMN1019USN for the MOSFET? (V_GS,max is +-8V) (edited to change part number to correct MOSFET)

What is your actual load? With 100 ohm load, you can't draw 100 mA from a 200 mV source no matter what your MOSFET does.

To further the above point…is your load really a 100ohm resistor or closer to a 100mA current sink?

The 100Ohm is just a random number I put into the simulation to illustrate the circuit without having to worry too much about the Rds(on) of the MOSFET. The true load will be closer to a 2-3Ohm load (hence the need to support 100mA at 200mV)

Yes, it will work, though you should be looking at the voltages for guaranteed Rds(on) rather than the threshold, since the latter is based on only 1mA and Vds of 10V. So add 200mV to the 1.2 to 2.5V to get the minimum input voltage for the given Rds(on).

With a 2.7V (or greater) drive you'd be guaranteed no more than 1.2Ω at 25°C so 120mV drop at 100mA, which doesn't sound great to me when you only have 200mV. Add maybe 50% for high temperature and your 200mV is almost gone.
Also, if the 100mA output went to some kind of inductive load it's possible that the maximum Vgs could come into play.

Thanks for confirming that this can work! As for the Rds(on): You're completely right, it turns out I put the wrong MOSFET part number in the question (I realized the issue with Rds(on) at some point in the past, but promptly forgot about it again when posting the question...). The actual part will be the DMN1019USN, which has a Rds(on)<12mΩ at currents up to 9A.

Due to all the voltage drops between the 0.2V source and the load, is there any reason why you're not just controlling the voltage reference for the 0.2V supply?
The supply, with such a low voltage, needs feedback (voltage sense) directly from the load. So, disconnecting the load would cause the supply to operate open loop. Not good for when the load is reconnected to the supply as the voltage will be too high during the turn-on transient.
Dropping 3V at 0.1A is just 0.3W of dissipated power. You could make a simple op-amp-controlled linear supply, regulating from a 3V source, with a little heatsink to dissipate those 0.3W, and then just set it to 0.2V or 0V output as needed. That sort of switching - on the voltage setpoint side - is much easier to do. And, if designed for it, the supply should transit between voltage setpoints without overshoot.
